# PDFBox merge PDF fragments without page break

Tags: java, pdfbox

Can I merge two PDF (one contains photo, second contains text) into one PDF using PDFBox, but requirement is to have single page document. PDFbox should take care of content alignment (photo should be above text)

Comment: It is possible two merge the contents of multiple pages on one page but you have to take care of content alignment yourself.

Comment: Is there any visitor I can use for stream to move contents by given  x and y?

Comment: @mkl can you provide some example?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265) for the technique.