# Building multiple pdf's into single pdf at particular positions

Tags: java, pdf

am having sub pdf's and i want to build main pdf that consists sub pdf's at particular positions . Is this possible , how can i do that.

Here is the image
[image]

Comment: *i want to build main pdf that consists sub pdf's at particular positions* - I assume those *sub pdf's* have only a signle page, or at least only a single page of each them them is of interest. In that case any general purpose PDF library should do. Some PDF libraries support that explicitly (e.g. iText and PdfClown), and for others the functionality is easy to add (e.g. PDFBox, cf. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265)).

Answer (score 1):

Not java, but C# solution - as an alternative PDF stamp (using [Debenu Quick PDF Library](http://debenu.com)):

```
DPL.AddToFileList("file_list", "file_1.pdf"); //file with one page
DPL.AddToFileList("file_list", "file_2.pdf"); //file with one page
DPL.AddToFileList("file_list", "file_3.pdf"); //file with one page
DPL.AddToFileList("file_list", "file_4.pdf"); //file with one page

DPL.MergeFileList("file_list", "merged_files.pdf"); //merge the files into a new document

DPL.LoadFromFile("merged_files.pdf", ""); //load the new merged file
DPL.InsertPages(1, 1);  //it is important to add a new blank page, becasue in the next steps the CapturePage function removes the pages and the document must have at least one page - the final page
int captured1 = DPL.CapturePage(2); 
int captured2 = DPL.CapturePage(2); //the captured page is removed, so page numbers are decreased
int captured3 = DPL.CapturePage(2);
int captured4 = DPL.CapturePage(2);

DPL.SelectPage(1);
DPL.DrawCapturedPage(captured1, 100, 200, 100, 100); //you can set your custom coordinates: left, top, widt, height
DPL.DrawCapturedPage(captured2, 200, 200, 100, 100);
DPL.DrawCapturedPage(captured3, 300, 200, 100, 100);
DPL.DrawCapturedPage(captured4, 400, 200, 100, 100);

DPL.SaveToFile("merged_files.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

As for pure Java solutions check out the recommendations of [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459213/building-multiple-pdfs-into-single-pdf-at-particular-positions?lq=1#comment41562004_26459213).

I tried the [PDFBox solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/4121087) and the [PDFClown solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26309525/4121087). Both work pretty well. In my opinion, PDFClown is more straightforward and thus less tedious when it comes to get things done. For example, there is less fiddling around with the coordinates which certainly helps arranging a multi-page.