# How do I rotate the contents of a PDF page to an arbitrary angle?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need to rotate the contents of a PDF page by an arbitrary angle and the PDPage.setRotation(int) command is restricted to multiples of 90 degrees. 
The contents of the page are vector and text and I need to be able to zoom in on the contents later, which means that I cannot convert the page to an image because of the loss of resolution.

Comment: You can't do this at the page level. But you can set a rotation by changing the current transformation matrix at the content stream level, i.e. by concatenating a rotated matrix instance to the CTM before doing your output.

Comment: If it suffices to draw some content, e.g. an existing regular portrait or landscape page, at an arbitrary angel onto a new regular portrait or landscape page, them you can use the mechanism presented [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265). If on the other hand you expect the page itself to be rotated at an arbitrary angle, you may believe @TilmanHausherr and Bruno.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, that works fine, once I had allowed for the API changes between the snapshots at the time of your post in Oct-2014 and the current 2.0.0 snapshots

Comment: Oh well, SNAPSHOTs... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In comments it already has been indicated that *to draw some content, e.g. an existing regular portrait or landscape page, at an arbitrary angle onto a new regular portrait or landscape page, one can use the mechanism presented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265).*

As the code presented there

1. requires the PDFBox development 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version and
2. makes use of form xobjects which in the context at hand is not necessary,

though, here a quick&dirty solution working for the current regular release 1.8.8 without introducing form xobjects.

This method

```
void transformPage(PDDocument document, PDPage page, AffineTransform at) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    PDRectangle cropBox = page.findCropBox();
    float xOffset = (cropBox.getUpperRightX() + cropBox.getLowerLeftX()) / 2f;
    float yOffset = (cropBox.getUpperRightY() + cropBox.getLowerLeftY()) / 2f;
    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(xOffset, yOffset);
    transform.concatenate(at);
    transform.concatenate(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-xOffset, -yOffset));

    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, false);
    stream.concatenate2CTM(transform);
    stream.close();

    COSBase contents = page.getCOSDictionary().getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);
    if (contents instanceof COSStreamArray)
    {
        COSStreamArray contentsArray = (COSStreamArray) contents;
        COSArray newArray = new COSArray();
        newArray.add(contentsArray.get(contentsArray.getStreamCount() - 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < contentsArray.getStreamCount() - 1; i++)
        {
            newArray.add(contentsArray.get(i));
        }

        COSStreamArray newStreamArray = new COSStreamArray(newArray);
        page.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.CONTENTS, newStreamArray);
    }
}
```

applies the given transformation to the given page. To make the use case at hands (to rotate the contents of a PDF page) easier, the transformation is enveloped in translations moving the origin of the coordinate system to the center of the page for the transformation.

The method can be used like this

```
try ( InputStream sourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("13.pdf") )
{
    final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceStream);
    final AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 4);

    List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

    for (PDPage page: pages)
    {
        transformPage(document, page, transform);
    }

    document.save("13-transformedPages.pdf");
}
```

to rotate the pages of a document counterclockwise by 45° (PI/4, mathematically positive rotation direction).

Answer (score 2):

Please read ISO-32000-1 (this is the ISO standard for PDF), more [specifically Table 30 ("Entries in a page object")](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf#page=86). It defines the `Rotate` entry like this (literal copy/paste):

> The number of degrees by which the page shall be rotated clockwise
>   when displayed or printed. The value shall be a multiple of 90.
>   Default value: 0.

Whenever an ISO standard uses the word *shall*, you are confronted a normative rule (as opposed to when the standard uses the word *should* in which case you're facing a recommendation).

In short: you are asking something that is explicitly forbidden by the PDF specification. Meeting your requirement is impossible in PDF. Your page can have an orientation of 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees. You will have to rotate the contents on the page instead of rotating the page.

Comment: My bad - I meant the contents of the page. I will change the question to reflect that.

Comment: I'm the iText guy. I know how to rotate content in PDF (and using iText), but I'm not familiar enough with PdfBox to answer your adapted question. You should look for methods that change the transformation matrix as explained by @TilmanHausherr

Answer (score 1):

I researched **mkl**'s answer and modified it for PDFBox version 2.0.4.

Here I provided example with a document of byte array type. But you can work with File and InputStream types as well. And the `rotationAngle` in radians.

```
public byte[] rotateDoc(byte[] source, double rotationAngle) throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(source);
    PDPageTree pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    PDRectangle mediaBox = pages.get(0).getCropBox();

    PDDocument target = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    page.setResources(new PDResources());
    page.setMediaBox(mediaBox);
    target.addPage(page);

    PDFormXObject xObject = importAsXObject(target, pages.get(0));
    page.getResources().add(xObject, "X");

    PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(target, page);
    float xOffset = (mediaBox.getUpperRightX() + mediaBox.getLowerLeftX()) / 2f;
    float yOffset = (mediaBox.getUpperRightY() + mediaBox.getLowerLeftY()) / 2f;

    AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(xOffset, yOffset);
    transform.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationAngle));
    transform.concatenate(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-xOffset, -yOffset));

    content.transform(new Matrix(transform));
    content.drawForm(xObject);
    content.close();

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    target.save(os);
    byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
    os.close();
    target.close();
    document.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

I also provide **importAsXObject** function previously submitted by **mkl**:

```
private PDFormXObject importAsXObject(PDDocument target, PDPage page) throws IOException {
    final InputStream src = page.getContents();
    if (src != null) {
        final PDFormXObject xObject = new PDFormXObject(target);

        OutputStream os = xObject.getStream().createOutputStream();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(src, os);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(src);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
        }

        xObject.setResources(page.getResources());
        xObject.setBBox(page.getCropBox());

        return xObject;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Btw you won't rotate the original document, but just put its rotated copy into another document. After rotation, some of the document content may not fit inside the original page. In this case, you can scale down the rotated content using the `AffineTransform.getScaleInstance` method. Just add it to the `transform` object as shown below (in the example it is reduced to 90%):

```
transform.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(0.9, 0.9));
```