# iTextsharp - Get rotation of pdf page in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i am trying to get/read rotation/degree of pdf page in c# using iTextsharp. i googled fully but nothing i found except below:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader inputPdf = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(txtBrowse.Text);
int rotation = inputPdf.GetPageRotation(PageNo);
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(rotation);
```

the above code does not return properly.

Please help me to get the rotation of the pdf page in c#.

Comment: What does it returns ?

Comment: it returns int value of 0,90,180,270 or 360

Comment: And isn't it the degree you are looking for ?

Comment: *it returns int value of 0,90,180,270 or 360* - only multiples of 90° are valid page rotation values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments of your question you say that your code returns int values of 0, 90, 180, 270 or 360. In your question, you claim that your code doesn't work. Your comment is in contradiction with your question.

Please read ISO-32000-1 (this is the ISO standard for PDF), more [specifically Table 30 ("Entries in a page object")](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf#page=86). It defines the `Rotate` entry like this (literal copy/paste):

> The number of degrees by which the page shall be rotated clockwise
>   when displayed or printed. The value shall be a multiple of 90.
>   Default value: 0.

Whenever an ISO standard uses the word *shall*, you are confronted a normative rule (as opposed to when the standard uses the word *should* in which case you're facing a recommendation).

What you say in your comment is in accordance with the PDF specification. If you expect any other value to be returned, then your expectation is wrong. See also [How do I rotate the contents of a PDF page to an arbitrary angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260880/how-do-i-rotate-the-contents-of-a-pdf-page-to-an-arbitrary-angle)

Comment: i need the rotated angle of pdf and not trying to rotate. the above work for some pdf and some for not.

i just asking how to get the rotation of pdf using atalasoft or itextsharp,

Comment: i opened one pdf in notepad and checked rotate value. the value is Rotate 270 but above code returns 0. this is what i have problem

Comment: Show us the PDF. Maybe you are looking at a page dictionary that isn't in use (for instance: because it has been overwritten in an incremental update).

Comment: Sorry.. i cant send that pdf because it is companies confidential documents.
Can u tell me, the above code is correct or is there any thing which i am missing. the below another sample

`iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(txtBrowse.Text);

iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(PageNo));
int i = doc.PageSize.Rotation;
            label1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);`

Comment: If you can't share the document publicly, you can share it privately on the closed issue tracker available to iText customers. This way, you have the guarantee that your document will be treated confidentially. If you are not an iText customer, then we can't help you. Have you seen this video: https://youtu.be/QHF3xcWnSD4 (If you are not a customer, you should probably share your complete code base.)

Comment: Will itextsharp get rotation for image type pdf? as checked it gets rotation of only searchable pdf.

please tell me how to upload the pdf i never did this before.

Comment: Your question becomes less and less clear. **Customers** can upload a file here: https://jira.itextsupport.com (but if you are not paying for your use of iText, you don't have access to iText Support!)