# appendDocument method of PDFBox not working

Tags: pdfbox

Following is the chunk of my code:

```
    PDFMergerUtility mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility();


    File f1 = new File("D:/out/pdf-sample.pdf");
    File f2 = new File("D:/out/Combined.pdf");

    PDDocument pd1 = PDDocument.load(f1);


    PDDocument pd2 = PDDocument.load(f2);

mergePdf.appendDocument(pd1, pd2);
```

There is no error on the console; but the content isn't just getting appended.

Comment: Did you save the destination document?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : Yes I did..

Comment: Your code does not show a save, that is why I asked. Make sure that you saved in the directory you expected. Check this with a debugger or do some trace. Find out whether the absolute path is really where you want, by doing `System.out.println (new File(yourdirstring).getAbsolutePath())`. There may be surprises with relative paths if you're on a server (e.g. tomcat).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : Hey Thanks mate... that worked...apparently there was some problem with the path. But now the resulting data is getting appended on the next page of the document. What I do want is the data to be appended on the same page..is there any way to achieve that.. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear that... either answer it yourself or delete the question. Now about "What I do want is the data to be appended on the same page" - `PDFMergerUtility` cannot do that. I'd recommend that you create a new question and include both PDFs. Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256546/how-to-insert-an-pdpage-within-another-pdpage-with-pdfbox

Answer (score 1):

```
    pd2.close();
    pd1.save(m_Dest);
    pd1.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate what this code snippet does and how does it solves the problem?

Comment: Please read [answer]. Brevity is fine, but fuller explanations are better. Remember you're writing for OP _and others who may find this question in the future!_