# Want to add content of pdf page to another pdf

Tags: pdfbox, pdfclown

I have two pdfs  both with limited data i.e. Single page. I want to merge the data of one pdf into another pdf but on the single page (It should not create the other page to append the external data). Is there any way to do this using pdfbox or pdfclown ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265) shows how you can import a page from one document and put it onto a page of another.

Comment: The link by mkl is the link that I pointed you to in my comment in your "merge" question. Could you please edit your question explaining why that answer is not helpful for you?