# create a one page PDF from several PDFs using PDFBOX

Tags: pdf, merge, pdfbox

I have several PDFs in different sizes and every PDF has only one page.
I want to place the PDFs on one page using PDFBOX.
How can I place them in a specific point?
I've only found ways to merge PDFs to multiple PDF BUT I need to place them on one page... any idea?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26299557/1729265) shows you how you can take an arbitrary source page, scale/move/rotate it, and put it onto a target page. As far as I understand your question, you merely need to apply that mechanism to multiple source pages and the same target page.

Comment: If the linked answer answers your question, I will close this question as duplicate thereof. Is that ok?