# How to merge PDF elements with Java

Tags: java, pdf, java-8, pdfbox

Can I merge elements from two PDF to a final PDF with PDFBox (or other library)?

I'm not looking for page concatenation but merging page elements:

[image]

Comment: Please comment the close vote

Comment: Both close votes are claiming your question is off-topic because it asks for a off-site resource recommendation. I assume the voters took your *"PDFBox (or other library)"* as a request for a library recommendation.

Comment: *"merge elements from two PDF to a final PDF"* - What exactly do you mean by that? From your words I would have thought you mean something akin to what the `PdfVeryDenseMergeTool` for iText does, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29078954/1729265). Your image, on the other hand, looks more like something the PDFBox `Overlay` class and `OverlayPDF` tool do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256546/

Comment: @mkl overlay is the answer. I follow this: https://snipplr.com/view/327056/pdfbox-overlaying-one-pdf-on-another/

Comment: @Tobia Do you want to make this an actual answer here or shall I?

Comment: Please proceed with the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task of the OP is to merge two pages into one, keeping each object at its present location on the page.

For doing this PDFBox provides the `Overlay` class. Given two `PDDocument` instances `document1` and `document2`, you can simply do

```
Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
overlay.setInputPDF(document1);
overlay.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(document2);

Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();            
overlay.overlay(ovmap);

document1.save("");

overlay.close();
```

to overlay the second over the first document.

But the `Overlay` can be used for more complex overlaying tasks. In particular it allows you to also set specific PDFs to overlay only odd, only even pages, or only explicitly specified pages with.

As an example have a look at the source of the PDFBox tool `OverlayPDF`.

---

A word of warning, though: Only the page *content* of the extra documents is used for overlaying, all kinds of annotations are ignored. Also don't expect tags to be copied.